# How to Check or Uncheck All Child Nodes in TreeView

Tags: c#, winforms, tree, treeview

I have a Deselect button in my application, but its not working well. If I am going to deselect the folder it will deselect. But the folder within a subfolder will remain selected(checked).

Any help with this issue would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Can you show the relevant code (or even a screenhost) and be a little clearer on what your are trying to achieve (selection/checking)?

Comment: @RenéVogt See the screenshot... childnode remain selected!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should *find all nodes including descendants* and then set `Checked=false`.

For example you can use this extension method to get all descendant nodes of tree or descendants of a node:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public static class Extensions
{
    public static List<TreeNode> Descendants(this TreeView tree)
    {
        var nodes = tree.Nodes.Cast<TreeNode>();
        return nodes.SelectMany(x => x.Descendants()).Concat(nodes).ToList();
    }

    public static List<TreeNode> Descendants(this TreeNode node)
    {
        var nodes = node.Nodes.Cast<TreeNode>().ToList();
        return nodes.SelectMany(x => Descendants(x)).Concat(nodes).ToList();
    }
}
```

Then you can use above methods on tree or a node to uncheck all descendant nodes of tree or uncheck all descendant nodes of a node:

**Uncheck descendant nodes of tree:**

```
this.treeView1.Descendants().Where(x => x.Checked).ToList()
              .ForEach(x => { x.Checked = false; });
```

**Uncheck descendant nodes of a node:**

for example for node 0:

```
this.treeView1.Nodes[0].Descendants().Where(x => x.Checked).ToList()
              .ForEach(x => { x.Checked = false; });
```

Don't forget to add `using System.Linq;`

Comment: Bro... checked= false, I have did this already, the thing is Main folder will be deselect but  subfolders should remain in selected state,

Comment: You said  *If i am going to deselect the folder it will deselect. but folder within a subfolder will remain selected(checked).* You want child nodes checked or unchecked?

Comment: i want to deselect all the nodes+childnodes at a time when i going to deselect the button!

Comment: It seems you didn't read the answer carefully. Add those extension methods that enabled you to get all nodes of a tree or all nodes of a node, then uncheck theme all.

Comment: I have attached screenshot! check it

Comment: Is this your requirement? "I want to uncheck a node and all sub nodes"

Comment: the childnode remains selected mode, Please Help me out

Comment: So the answer is **exactly** what you need. What's your problem with the answer?

Comment: give me a code for deselect all the nodes at a time when i click on the deselect button

Comment: Are you familiar with Extension Methods?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101288/discussion-between-reza-aghaei-and-santosh-kokatnur).

Comment: No comment. +1 for the patience (and the answer of course:)